# Pin Point Theorem & Pin Point-Reverse Theorem Calculation

Tags: education

I was given this question to do over the weekend by my professor and I'm at a roadblock. We wont over the theorem during class but I cant seem to find much about it. Any help in solving this would be appreciated:

[Pin Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pz4d.png)

> The origin is x=0 and I'm told to find the point at which the blue line is x=0.34f using both the pin point and pin point-reverse theorem. Given that the green line which pins to 1.3334 by the pin point-reverse theorem is perpendicular to the light blue line at x=0.34f.

I'm not sure whether the pin point theorem will generate a finite number given the circumstances of the problem. Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Given that you are required to use both the pin point, and pin point reverse theorem, otherwise known as the cc theorem (iam calamum, et e converso) a theorem that I hold very close to my heart as it is quite difficult for those not well versed in the study of ancient arithmetic.*

If the green line pins at 1.3334 and the blue line pins at 0.34, relative to the orgin of 0, My answer would be **0.45^2 x 0/π**